# How to set permissions in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, permissions, rdd

I am working on a setup that involves Apache Spark. 
The problem right now is that not all users are allowed to view the same content.

In my setup it's required for people to use eachothers scripts to interact with the data, but it's important that people can only view the data they are allowed to view. How can I achieve this with(in) Apache Spark?

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/sparksql-ranger-and-llap-via-spark-thrift-server-f

Comment: Thanks for the link, seems like a very good article. Only the option only works if you run Spark on Hadoop right?

Comment: Yes I think so. But that is pretty common. You can run without Hadoop, but ...